# Is possible to secure interaction between Rest api and CouchDB in Hyperledger

Tags: rest, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am new in hyperledger technologie. I created a network file (.bna) and deployed this successfully using composer-rest-server command. Also I create CouchDB for every peers in the network. Have any idea about to secure the couchDB from outside attack. And is any way how to secure the interaction
between Rest api and couchDB. Please give any idea or some good practice about this security issue.

OS:Ubuntu 16.04

Fabric: 1.1.0

Composer:0.19.16

Node: 8.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composer does not interact directly with the CouchDB service, only the Peers interact with CouchDB.

As a minimum you would setup CouchDB to use a complex Admin ID and password (I think the default is NO password), and you would configure your network security such that only the peers can see/connect to the couchDB server.

This doc gives some more information about [using and securing CouchDB with Fabric](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/couchdb_as_state_database.html#using-couchdb-from-chaincode).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I understand that setup CouchDB to use a complex Admin ID and password. But I don't understand how to apply configure the network security such that only the peers can see/connect to the couchDB server. Please comment if any idea.

Comment: The network security element would be managed by firewalls and or DMZs or docker /kubernetes networking.

Comment: Thanks again for commenting